# Ошибка "Prefix creation exited with error: You find a logfile to help with debugging on your desktop" при запуске .exe файл на macOS с помощью Wine

Tags: файлы, macos, exe, wine

При попытке запустить .exe файл на macOS с помощью Wine возникает такая ошибка... Кто знает, как ее устранить?

Log ошибки:

```
###BOTTLING### customprefix.sh
/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh: line 39: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine: Bad CPU type in executable
###BOTTLING### Gathering debug Info...

Versions
OS...........................: darwin22
Wine.........................: 
WineBottler..................: 1.8.6
Wineticks....................: 20230212-next - sha256sum: cf1e17a69db4126779e597def9facdecbb0703a20ed7172dd877b1f7824d66ec

Environment
PWD..........................: '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin'
PATH.........................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
USER.........................: polina
HOME.........................: /Users/polina
COMPUTERNAME.................: MacBook ProÂ â Polina
BUNDLERESOURCEPATH...........: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources
WINEPREFIX...................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources
WINEPATH.....................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH..............: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/lib:/opt/X11/lib:/usr/X11/lib
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH...: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/lib:/usr/lib:/opt/X11/lib:/usr/X11/lib
SILENT.......................: 
http_proxy...................: 
https_proxy..................: 
ftp_proxy....................: 
socks5_proxy.................: 

Bottle
TEMPLATE.....................: 
BOTTLE.......................: /Users/polina/Wine Files
INSTALLER_URL................: 
INSTALLER_IS_ZIPPED..........: 0
INSTALLER_NAME...............: 
INSTALLER_ARGUMENTS..........: 
REMOVE_MONO..................: 
REMOVE_GECKO.................: 
REMOVE_USERS.................: 
REMOVE_INSTALLERS............: 
WINETRICKS_ITEMS.............: 
DLL_OVERRIDES................: 
EXECUTABLE_PATH..............: notneeded
EXECUTABLE_ARGUMENTS.........: 
EXECUTABLE_VERSION...........: 1.0.0
BUNDLE_COPYRIGHT.............: 
BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER............: org.kronenberg.winebottler
BUNDLE_CATEGORYTYPE..........: public.app-category.utilities
SILENT.......................: 

Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro18,3
      Model Number: MKGR3LL/A
      Chip: Unknown
      Total Number of Cores: 8 (6 performance and 2 efficiency)
      Memory: 16 GB
      System Firmware Version: 8419.80.7
      OS Loader Version: 8419.80.7
      Serial Number (system): XMV7W2HDWK
      Hardware UUID: 4994473B-A563-509C-A4F1-E9F20DDF59FB
      Provisioning UDID: 4994473B-A563-509C-A4F1-E9F20DDF59FB
      Activation Lock Status: Enabled

###BOTTLING### Enabling CoreAudio, Colors, Antialiasing  and flat menus...
/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh: line 134: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine: Bad CPU type in executable
### LOG ### Command '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine regedit /tmp/reg.reg' returned status 126.



###ERROR### Command '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine regedit /tmp/reg.reg' returned status 126.
Task returned with status 1.
```

Вопрос не совсем по программированию, но все же, может кто-нибудь сталкивался? Wine никогда не пользовался

Comment: Ошибка  "Bad CPU type in executable"  говорит о том что вы скорее всего пытаетесь запускать 32 битную версию wine нужно wine64 и префикс тоже изначально должен быть создан в 64 версии https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=36148, MACлонники как всегда идут в отрыв игноря реалии и потребности.... https://support.apple.com/en-us/103076#:~:text=Apple%20has%20been%20working%20with,no%20longer%20compatible%20with%20macOS.